# SQL The multi-part identifier "c.clerkID" could not be bound

Tags: sql-server, error-handling

I am trying to run a query, Where I am looking to find the names of the staff who made the most booking. I can manage to get the result without their first name but when I try to find the first name it gives me error of :

> The multi-part identifier "c.clerkID" could not be bound

The code I am using is this:

```
select 
clerkFName
from ( 
        SELECT c.clerkID,  COUNT( * ) AS totalBookings
        FROM bookings b
        GROUP BY c.clerkID
        )T
 INNER JOIN clerks as c ON b.clerkID = c.clerkID
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: @xaim check the update i have missed from in select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You gave your group by query a new alias T. From that point on when referencing data from that subquery, you have to use that alias (T). Also in the subquery you were referencing c.clerkID. This should have been b.clerkID So this should do it:

```
select clerkFName,totalBookings from ( SELECT b.clerkID, COUNT( * ) AS totalBookings 
FROM bookings b GROUP BY b.clerkID ) T
INNER JOIN clerks as c ON T.clerkID = c.clerkID;
```

Comment: many thanks for your help but now, it doesn't show the amount of bookings they took, its only showing me their first names

Comment: To get the amount of booking, update the select with:
"select clerkFName, totalBookings from etc"
You did just not put it in the select, that is all.

Comment: Hi Norbert van Nobelen it doesnt work, the answer you provided only giving me first names now

Comment: My edited query should give totalBookings too as response, please re-test

Comment: Thanks Alot it worked :)
i need help with another one would you kind enough to help?